# I cannot hide an element inside a DIV with different ID and CLASS via CSS

Tags: css

I cannot hide a H2 element inside a DIV using CSS, please help me.. Heres the CSS:

```
<style>
#block-views-projects-block h2 {
visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
```

And heres the actual html code

```
<div class="region region-projects">
    <div id="block-views-projects-block" class="block block-views contextual-links-region">
    <h2>PROJECTS</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you give me the correct CSS to remove this H2 PROJECTS , I cannot remove it as it is produced automatically. Note: the DIV's from this code has a different css ID's and CLASS.

Comment: I tested it on fiddle. Its hiding the `h2` element.

Comment: @LayoutPH try to use display:none; instead of visibility:hidden;

Comment: Yeah @Sandeep. It works for me too, here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4NCg5/

Comment: Guys thank you for the fiddle link. I think there must be an overlapping CSS commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
#block-views-projects-block h2 {
display: none;
```

}

if this doesn't work, then can you try this

```
#block-views-projects-block h2 {
display: none !important;
```

}